# Wordpress with Gulp & Browser-sync is not loading index page anymore (can't redirect)

Tags: wordpress, gulp, browser-sync

I was developing a Wordpress theme using Gulp & Browsersync normally.
But now I can't access to the homepage : It says something like 'can't redirect'.
Still, I can access to the back-end (wp-admin).

Everything was OK until I had to change the Site title (through back-end > Settings > General).

1. The Home URL was set to `//localhost:3000/mysite`, I don't know how it was set that way.
2. I couldn't save my page as this Home URL was not conform to Wordpress, so I changed it to `http://localhost:3000/mysite`.
3. Then I could access to Wordpress homepage, but I was able to access Wordpress back-end (wp-admin).
4. So I changed the siteurl & home to `//localhost:3000/mysite` again directly in the database. Then, I couldn't do anything (go to either front-end or back-end).
5. I put back `http://localhost:3000/mysite` in the database and clicked twice to save Permalinks : But this didn't changed anything.

When I change the Home + Site URL to `http://localhost:8888/mysite`, everything is working well.
I guess it's coming from BrowserSync who was able to set the port to 3000.

Here is my gulpfile about BrowserSync, I'm proxying the 8888 port as I'm using MAMP :

```
/****** BrowserSync ******/

const server = browserSync.create();
export const serve = done => {
  server.init({
    proxy: "localhost:8888/humblyhealthy", // put your local website link here
    snippetOptions: {
      ignorePaths: "wp-admin/**"
    }
  });
  done();
};
export const reload = done => {
  server.reload();
  done();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by updating the Home + Site URL to `http://localhost:8888/mysite` in the database.

And I added `http://` to proxy on my gulpfile.

```
  server.init({
    proxy: "http://localhost:8888/humblyhealthy", // put your local website link here
```

I think it re-initialized the browsersync server after that.
Because, now when I go into the back-end to Settings > General : Home & Site URL are now automatically set to `//localhost:3000/humblyhealthy`.